# Returning false when number is > 1 in SQL

Tags: sql, select, case

I'm trying to compare if a number (integer) is greater than 0 in SQL.

The problem is when the number is greater than 1 it returns less (false).

I'm using [W3schools database](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_join_left) to test my query. I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
   OD.OrderID as OrderID, 
   OD.ShipperID, 
   (SELECT CASE OD.ShipperID 
         WHEN OD.ShipperID > 0 Then 'greater' 
         ELSE 'less' END) as Result 
   FROM Orders OD;
```

For when ShipperID is the following:

```
1 = greater
2 = less
3 = less
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case the correct syntax would be to use `CASE WHEN` instead of `CASE <value> WHEN`. Also a wrapped SELECT is not necessary.

```
SELECT OD.OrderID as OrderID
    , OD.ShipperID
    , CASE WHEN OD.ShipperID > 0 Then 'greater' ELSE 'less' END as Result 
FROM Orders OD;
```

Answer (score 1):

When using the more robust `case` syntax, you shouldn't have an expression between the `case` and the `when` clauses. The inner `select` is also redundant:

```
SELECT OD.OrderID as OrderID, 
       OD.ShipperID, 
       CASE WHEN OD.ShipperID > 0 THEN 'greater' ELSE 'less' END AS Result 
FROM   Orders OD;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT OD.OrderID as OrderID
     , OD.ShipperID
     , CASE WHEN OD.ShipperID > 0 THEN 'greater' 
            WHEN OD.ShipperID < 0 THEN 'less'
            ELSE 'same' END as Result
FROM Orders OD;
```

Comment: It would be helpful if the answer described more about the ways in which this query is different than the OP's original query. This probably works, but code-only answers do less to help the reader understand.'